# Warning: Unable to fully load /node_modules/ag-grid-angular/main.js for source-map flattening

Tags: angular, angular9, ag-grid-angular

I am getting the following warning when I am building the application with Angular Cli version 9.1.7 with enableIvy. I am using ag-grid-community version 22.1.0.

Warning: Unable to fully load /node_modules/ag-grid-angular/main.js for source-map flattening: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/node_modules/ag-grid-angular/exports.js.map

Application is running fine but still like to know, is this issue from ag-grid side? I didn't check ag-grid 23 version, so can this issue be resolved or not arise on the latest version. Thoughts..

Comment: this issue is still happening for angular version 9.1.11.  The warning is coming during the compilation of typescript sources through ngc. The following message is showing on the console "Compiling ag-grid-angular : main as commonjs" then the warning is coming.

Comment: Different from this context, another warning is coming during ng build "Warning: Entry point 'ngx-papaparse' contains deep imports into '/node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.min.js'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
" but this issue is already recognized by ngx-papaparse stakeholders and they are already in the process to fix it.

Comment: I'm getting this error with different dependencies and with Angular 11

Answer (score 18):

For me, the command `npm dedupe` solved the problem.

Description of `npm dedupe`

> Searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify the overall
> structure by moving dependencies further up the tree, where they can
> be more effectively shared by multiple dependent packages.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me to fix a very critical migration warning issues in my project! this question should be marked as Solved

Answer (score 8):

My experience and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35757 suggest deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file fixes this issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the same warning. It seems that everything is working, but I would like to get rid of this warning....

Comment: Yeah it seems after runing `ng update --all` the warnings came back. Re-deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock` cleared the warnings but it is not a viable solution  for me :/

Comment: Actually we can see this warning during ng build after fresh npm install. This will happen only when we build with ivy compiler, during this process ivy compiler compiles all those packages to esm5/esm2015

Comment: @Sanj I had the same issue exactly after a fresh `npm install`. The second time doing `ng build` has no warnings

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the node_modules and having the folder recreated automatically by running "npm install" did it for me.